# Difference between "given" and "sampled from" in an expectation

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation, machine-learning

I'm reading a paper that states that trajectories $\tau$ are sampled from a distribution $\pi$ and they use the notation for the expectation $\mathbb{E}_{\tau \sim \pi}$ but also use $\mathbb{E}_{\tau | \pi}$ and I can't say I'm sure what the difference really is.

While $\mathbb{E}_{\tau \sim \pi}$ is obvious in that the trajectories, $\tau$, are sampled from the distribution $\pi$, the latter isn't as obvious to me.

Thank you.

The paper in question is this one: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.05477.pdf#appendix.A

Comment: Looks very much like a notational inconsistency to me -- the $\mathbb{E}_{\tau | \pi}$ notation is never introduced, and where they say "Rearranging, the result follows." that seems to imply that they mean the same thing as $\mathbb{E}_{\tau \sim \pi}$, since that's what it says in the result.

Comment: @joriki Thanks for your comment. I figured the same but I constantly see this happening in ML papers so it's difficult for me to tell...